# Oracle 10g: anonymous block which writes to a file completes before file is completely written

Tags: oracle, plsql, io, oracle10g

I noticed that if I run an anonymous block in Oracle, which writes to a file, it will complete before the file is completely written out. What I see as that the anonymous block completes successfully, and after that, for some time after it is completed, the file to which it is writing out keeps increasing in size. Is there a way to make the anonymous block to complete only after the file is completely written out?

Below is example of code from anonymous block responsible for writing to file:

> ```
>         v_file :=
>            UTL_FILE.fopen (dir_name,
>                            file_name,
>                            'a',
>                            32760);
>         vn_offset := 1;
>
>         WHILE (vn_offset < vn_length)
>         LOOP
>            vs_substr := DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (data, vi_chunk_size, vn_offset);
>
>            UTL_FILE.put (v_file, REPLACE (vs_substr, CHR (13), CHR (10)));
>
>            UTL_FILE.fflush (v_file);
>            vn_offset := vn_offset + vi_chunk_size;
>         END LOOP;
>
>
>         UTL_FILE.new_line (v_file);
>         UTL_FILE.fclose (v_file);
> ```

Comment: What is the operating system you are using? If it is a GUI like Windows or Linux, are you sure the window is done refreshing? It is unlikely that Oracle would return to console saying the code execution is complete before all the IO threads are closed.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative is to use the following code for writing out a CLOB to a file:

```
  dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file(flocation => p_dir
                                 ,fname     => p_filename
                                 ,cl        => p_clob
                                 ,csid      => nls_charset_id('WE8ISO8859P1'));
```

If the problem remains it's probably an underlying OS or network issue.